# how to manage microservice online?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

spring cloud or kubernates for service govern？
i want to use spring cloud to build microservice,but if the many microservices is online,it will have many online problem,such as Gray release ,monitor,version rollback and so on?what technolygy should use to manage microservices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud and Kubernetes are the best environments for developing and running microservices, but they are both very different in nature and address different concerns.Spring cloud covers logging, monitoring, service discovery but not scaling and high availability which are very important for Microservice architecture.

Spring cloud has a rich set of java libraries for runtime concerns like client-side service discovery, load balancing, configuration update and metrics. Whereas Kubernetes is not only for Java platform and it doesn't need any specific libraries for service discovery, load balancing, metrics and scheduled jobs. For some areas like logging both use third-party tools like ELK.

[image]

> Spring Cloud

- Rich set of libraries help the developers to integrates different services easily.
- Limited to only java
- Scaling and high availability is not achieved unless taken care by an orchestrator.

> Kubernetes

- Is an open-source container management platform which helps to create different environments like dev, test, demo..
- Allows to provision resource constraints, scaling and high availability.

It all depends on the use case.Hope this helps.

References :

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/12/09/spring-cloud-for-microservices-compared-to-kubernetes/

http://blog.christianposta.com/microservices/netflix-oss-or-kubernetes-how-about-both/